# Inner Join array result with another table id, name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join, foreach

Is it possible to take the results of an array and join it with another table ID in order to output the ID's name?

This is the output of the array:  `Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 )`

This is mysql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    meet 
    INNER JOIN location 
    ON meet.meetLoc = location.locID 
    LEFT JOIN team ON meet.meetTeams = team.teamID 
ORDER BY meetDate ASC
```

This is the PHP, however, it only outputs "3 : 1 : 2" when I need "Bob : Sally : Sue":

```
$teams = explode(", ", $row_rsCurMeet['meetTeams']);
$tmp = array();
foreach ($teams as $team)
$tmp[] = $team;
echo implode('&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;',$tmp);
```

I have also tried this but it returns "Bob : Bob : Bob"

```
$team_id = $row_rsCurMeet['teamID'];    
$team_name = $row_rsCurMeet['teamName'];
$team = $row_rsCurMeet['teamName'];
$teams = explode(", ", $row_rsCurMeet['meetTeams']);
foreach ($teams as $key => $value) {
$key = $team_id;
$value = $team_name;
print_r ($value);
}
```

Any thoughts?  My head hurts from beating it against the wall.  Thanks!

```
SAMPLE DATA

Table meet             Table  team
meetID  meetTeams      teamID   teamName
1        3, 1, 2         1      Sally
2        2, 3, 1         2      Sue
3        1, 3, 2         3      Bob
```

Please disregard the Location information as it's not an issue.

Comment: can we see an example of the data?

Comment: Where is "Bob : Sally : Sue" coming from? Can you add the table defs and some sample data?

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you are trying to do. I don't know what you mean by `results of an array`.  An array is just an array, it doesn't have results.  I am not sure what you mean by outputting an `ID's name either`.  You are showing little snippets of code with context as to how they fit together.  Perhaps just give us a more real-world explanation of what you are trying to do.  Start with the table schemas and tell us what you are looking to output.  My guess is whatever you are looking to do can easily be solved by making sure your query is right.

Comment: @MikeBrant   Thanks for responding.  I added sample data to my question.  Ultimately I need to take the data from "meetTeams" and join it to the teamID and display teamName.  My sql statement seems fine, however, the PHP code seems to be where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: @TorreyShoaff Is that data in the `meetTeams` field really a comma-separated list like that?

Comment: @MikeBrant  Yes.  I have a form on another page that chooses which team members will be attending a meeting.  The teamName is chosen from a Multiple Select and stored like that in meetTeams.  If there is a better way to store the information I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your #1 problem is that you have a schema change that you need to make if you want to be able to actually relate meets to teams. Having a value in meet.meetTeams like `1,2,3` is preventing you from being able to do a meaningful join on the teams table.

So, my suggestion is that you remove the `meet.meetTeams` column altogether in favor of a new table `meetTeams` (or whatever you want to call it) that has a structure like this

```
meetId    teamID
------    ------
  1         1
  1         2
  1         3
  2         1
  2         2
  2         3
etc.
```

You would then query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    meet 
    INNER JOIN location 
    ON meet.meetLoc = location.locID 
    INNER JOIN meetTeams
    ON meet.meetID = meetTeams.meetID
    INNER JOIN team
    ON meetTeams.teamID = team.teamID 
ORDER BY meet.meetDate ASC
```

If all you really need to do is list the meets and teams, you can probably drop the location table from your query. You could also limit the field returned by not doing `SELECT *` and just returning the fields you need.

Now you might need to take the result set and read it into a multi-dimensional array, with `meetID` as first dimension.  This is easy enough to do. It might look something like this:

```
$meet_array = array()
while ($row = [YOUR PHP TO RETRIEVE ROW ARRAY FROM RESULT SET]) {
   $meet_array[$row['meetID']] = $row;
}

foreach ($meet_array as $meet_id => $meet_data) {
    echo 'Meet ID: ' . $meet_id . ' <br />';
    foreach ($meet_data as $data) {
        echo 'Team ID: ' . $data['teamID'] . ', Team Name: ' . $data['teamName'] . ' : ';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike!  I'll give that a try.  It makes perfect sense to create the other table.  Now I just need to rethink the form page that stores the data in the new meetTeams table.  I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I'm stuck on this part:  [YOUR PHP TO RETRIEVE ROW ARRAY FROM RESULT SET]   What is an example of that?  I've tried a few things but end of with a blank browser page.

Comment: I left that undefined as it was unclear as to what method you we using to interact with the database (i.e. `mysqli`, `PDO`, or something custom).  This really shouldn't be any different than how you were retrieving the result set from the database before.

Comment: If you're available for paid consultation please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: @TorreyShoaff I do some limited consulting work, but it is typically on enterprise-scale projects (i.e. web services at global scales, data stores dealing with hundreds of millions of records, etc.) so I would probably not be economical for this sort of project :)